# how to show my docxfile data in my webpage from database in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a database where the datapath of docxfiles are saved..These datapath are in my hard drive..i want to show the docxfile exactly the same in my webpage..in my docxfile there may be some texts inside  a table and there may be some images..i want to show the exact docxfile into my webpage..i don't know how to do it...

i have seen a code from retrieving data from database which are stored in my APP_DATA folder

```
@{
var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Persons.docx");
Array userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Reading Data from a File</h1>
@foreach (string dataLine in userData) 
{
foreach (string dataItem in dataLine.Split(',')) 
{@dataItem <text>&nbsp;</text>}
<br />
}
</body>
</html>
```

i don't know whether this will show the exact data with pictures or data inside the table that means how the data is written in the docxfile...

Comment: Better solution for like this requirement is, read the data from 'docx' file and convert to PDF.  Then it easy to show on a web page.

Comment: how to do it by coding?? can u give me some source or code???

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var data = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Persons.docx"));
     HiddenField1.Value = data.ToString();   
}
```

Here `HiddenField1` is `asp control` in my case.

Follow below link to get more information

[How To Write Binary Files to the Browser Using ASP.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

refer this link i hope it will help you.
[Preview Word files (docx) in HTML using ASP.NET](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/01/11/Preview-Word-files-%28docx%29-in-HTML-using-ASPNET-OpenXML-and-LINQ-to-XML.aspx)

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19642415/2798643)

Answer (score 0):

Google for the code to convert the `.docx` to `.pdf` file and you can refer the following code part to show the pdf file in webpage.

```
                string strFileLocation = @"D:\PdfFile\Ref_12345.pdf";          
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", ";filename=\"" + strFileLocation + "\"");
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
                Response.TransmitFile(strFileLocation);
```