# Http get method that return pdf file loaded from C: disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I want a function that load/read a pdf file that's stored in specific path into C disk, and return this as pdf.
First of all, i should use WebApi Controller or MVC Controller? Also, can anyone of this controllers read a file stored inside C: disk?

What headers should use to return a pdf file?

i some similar cases, but no one help me.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640590/reading-from-a-local-text-file-into-c)

Comment: If you have written some code for this but you can't get it to work, then you have come to the right place: just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question. Without that we cannot help. Please see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return PDF to browser in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510451/how-to-return-pdf-to-browser-in-mvc)