# Arrays and text files

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files

I would like to take a text file with a lot of lines and turn it into an array. For example if the text file was:

> Line 1
>
> Line 2
>
> Line 3
>
> Line 4`

It would result in

```
string[] stringList = { "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3", "Line 4" };
```

How do I do this?

I've tried this:

```
string line;
string[] accountList;
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(accountFileLocation.Text))
            {
                while (line = file.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    stringList += line;
                }
            }
```

However that errors with:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'
>
> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'string[]'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'

Comment: By learning how to code and then applying your knowledge. What have you tried?

Comment: Forgot to add what I tried to the post, added it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use

```
  string[] lines =  File.ReadAllLines(yourpathFile);
```

Comment: Will that automatically put them into a different string for each line? Or just one big string?

Comment: each line terminate with \r\n will be a different  item in  the array

Comment: There's a lot of lines (a few thousand) in the text file. Is there a way to do it without \r\n?

Comment: can you  explain more please

Comment: So I want each line in a text file (where there are a few thousand lines) to an individual string in the array. Is there a part you don't understand?

Comment: ok this method will work  fine even  if you have a thousands of lines

Comment: So do I have to add \r\n to the end of every line? There's too many lines to go through and add that to every line.

Comment: @chipperyman573 No `\r\n` indicates the end of the line, so basically if you see them as seperate lines in notepad, then they end with a newline already.

Comment: normally you don't see  \r\n if it a multilines file it will terminate  like this  it's a normal behavior you don't need to add anything

Comment: There is also File.ReadLines which is lazily enumerated line by line, not to forget. Should be better for large files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll walk you through how I came across the solution as learning what to Google is an important skill in finding solutions.

If you Google 'How to open a text file in c#' you find this webpage http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx
which uses a class called 'StreamReader' and its method 'ReadToEnd()' in an example it gives you.

If you then go on to Google 'c# StreamReader' you can find all of its methods that it has http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

If you scroll down to the R methods you can find one called 'ReadLine'. By clicking into it you can find a working example of exactly what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader();
String content = file.readToEnd();
file.close();
String[] lines = content.split("\n".toCharArray());
```

Comment: This would leave `\r` at the end of every line when it is in Windows format, even so it is not very smart to read everything in a sinlge string and then split it again.

Answer (score 0):

just try :

```
string n = "line1\r\nline2\r\n";
string[] list = n.Split('\r'); //or string[] list = n.Split('\n')
```