# Extract filtered list from large list

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to figure out a quick way of getting a filtered array via a "File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");" request, I have a text file containing a few thousand names, basically I would only require a list of names which have any of the following characters, I SQL this would be a "select" statment with a few "OR" conditions added, so my code is something like this...

```
var allowedChars = ["v","h","r"];
var allNames = File.ReadAllLines("names.txt");
```

so names like "david", "john" and "larry" would be what I'd expect
but names like "peter", "simon" and "paul" wouldn't be included

I know I could use a foreach to do this but was wondering is there some linq one liner I could implement to achieve this, also the "allowedChars" array may have varying lengths, any help would be great.

Comment: You should use `ReadLines`, not `ReadAllLines`, to allow you to stream the data rather than forcing you to read the entire file's contents into memory.

Comment: @Servy only "a few thousand names" in the file though.

Comment: @Blorgbeard You never know how fast the file will grow.  Were it to be a lot of work to stream the data, you could consider not doing it, but it literally is as simple as removing those five letters.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm going with "Yuriy Faktorovich" suggestion, looks the prettiest ;) and works as I need, thanks again.

Comment: @Servy true, but you also have to be aware that `allNames` is now an IEnumerable rather than an array, and that multiple enumeration will read the file multiple times (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: @Blorgbeard Sure, and if the OP uses a solution below he's still performing all of that processing each time the sequence is enumerated, so it's *already* important to not enumerate the query multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

```
var allowedNames = allNames.Where(n => allowedChars.Any(c => n.IndexOf(c) > -1));
```

Although as the file gets bigger, you might want to consider some kind of database solution or at least using

```
var items = new List<string();
const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) 
      if (allowedChars.Any(c => line.IndexOf(c) > -1))
        items.Add(line);
  }
```

so you're not loading them all into memory at the same time.

Comment: Rather than adding all of that extra code to try to stream the data, you can simply use `File.ReadLines` along with a standard LINQ solution.  Doing so will stream the data, and in fact allow the results to be streamed (through, say, a `foreach`) rather than materializing the filtered results into a `List`, as you have.

Comment: @Servy I'm sure you're right, it's the more readable solution. I googled fastest way to read file lines and came upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
var allowedChars = new char[] {'v','h','r'};
var allNames = new string[] { "peter", "paul", "victor", "hans" };

var names = allNames.Where(t => allowedChars.Any(c => t.Contains(c)));
```