# What's the most efficient way to read a very large file in chunks?

Tags: c#, csv, file-io

I want to read a CSV file which can be at a size of hundreds of GBs and even TB.
I got a limitation that I can only read the file in chunks of 32MB. 
My solution to the problem works kinda slow and I wanted to ask if you know of a better solution:

```
const int MAX_BUFFER = 33554432; //32MB
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
int bytesRead;

using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
{
    string line;
    bool stop = false;
    while ((bytesRead = bs.Read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != 0) //reading only 32mb chunks at a time
    {
        var stream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(buffer));
        while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //process line
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I'm adding a restriction saying that I cannot read the file line by line.

Comment: Have you tried `File.ReadLines` performance?

Comment: @KonradKokosa could you give an explanation and example in an answer? to be honest I'm not that experienced with file handling so I'm not sure what's the difference between File.ReadLines and the way I did it

Comment: BTW: according to your code, a line may be splitted in two chunks.

Comment: @L.B what do you mean?

Comment: @YonatanNir Take a look at the documentation, use Google to find examples, etc.  Come here if, after doing some basic research you're still struggling to use it.  I *highly* doubt that would happen though.  It's use is *far* easier than the alternatives, such as what you're trying to do.

Comment: @YonatanNir a line's first half may be in one chunk and the other half  in the next chunk.

Comment: Where do you think is the bottleneck? Reading from the file? or creating a new Stream from the buffer? or is it expected given that the files are so huge? One option could be to use multithreaded read where one thread reads while other one performs the rest of the stuff and vice versa.

Comment: Underneath `File.ReadLines` is calling `stream.ReadLine` sequentially but maybe it will be faster than overhead from buffering paradoxically.

Comment: BufferedStream is redundant with FileStream.

Comment: @Servy the question is this: is File.ReadAllLines() just easier to write, or is it also more efficient?

Comment: Why do you need to create 32MB chunks?  Why not use StreamReader directly over the file?

Comment: @YonatanNir Who said anything at all about `ReadAllLines`?  The comment was to use `File.ReadLines`, which is an entirely different method.  It is going to stream the data, rather than eagerly loading it into memory, it will have a convenient to use syntax, and is almost certainly sufficiently performant.

Comment: @wdosanjos that's a limitation I got.. I can't assume I can fit the entire file to the memory

Comment: There's no need to jump through all those hoops. There is a [StreamReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a2z3f9a.aspx) that lets you specify the buffer size. Also, consider defining your constant as `const int MAX_BUFFER = 32 * 1024 * 1024;` That's a whole lot more clear than the magic number. By the way, I've found that optimum buffer size is usually around 64 kilobytes. A bigger buffer just adds needless overhead, and usually makes your program slower.

Comment: @YonatanNir But you don't need to specifically use a 32MB sized buffer; you can use whatever makes the most sense.  If you just read one line at a time it will be automatically buffered to a sensible buffer size; there is no need to buffer a second time.

Comment: Could a line be larger than 32MB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Comment: @Servy I want to add a restriction that I can't read the entire file line by line

Comment: @YonatanNir And why is that?  What's wrong with doing that?

Comment: @Servy since this is the restriction I got: "You cannot read the entire file, one line at a time. Maximum size of data read, except for the actual records that need to be returned for the query, cannot exceed 32MB."
And I'm just not sure how to do it efficiently.

Comment: @YonatanNir And how is you explicitly buffering the data instead of using the existing .NET class that will do it for you any better?  Especially given that your implementation isn't even working?  If you want a working implementation use the framework's method, instead of re-writing it from scratch.  If there is a problem with it, then *explain what the problem is* otherwise someone else will re-write the same reader with the exact same problem.

Comment: @Servy what I wrote DOES work but it's slow. Given this restrictions I wanted to know what can be done in order to make it work faster.

Comment: @YonatanNir What you wrote *won't* work.  Every 32 MB it will add in a line break that wasn't there before.  If you want to improve its performance then say *that*, rather than adding arbitrary restrictions that are only likely to *harm* performance.  And if performance is your only concern here, then try the method proposed to you and see if it is sufficient for your purposes before rejecting it.

Comment: @Servy the title of this question is: "Read efficiently chunks of a very large file". I already wrote there that I'm searching for efficient ways of reading a file IN CHUNKS. Everyone were more comfortable with the simple line by line solution. 
I'm not saying that this way of reading the file is bad and it's probably even better, but I'm not the one that made the restrictions. I'm just passing them here as they were given to me.

Comment: @YonatanNir If you have some academic assignment of re-writing `BufferedStream` then go ahead and re-write it.  It's right there to use as an example.  It rather defeats the purpose if you just ask us to do it all for you.  The .NET library has already done it for you

Comment: @AndreiRinea, the `interview-questions` tag was [*intentionally* destroyed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142869/135887).  Please do not add it to any more questions.

Comment: You actually have two issues with line breaks. One, the way you're going about this will introduce artificial line breaks, as others have pointed out. Also, CSV can have line breaks within a field, which you'll have to account for. You'll probably want to read this byte by byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest simply using `File.ReadLines` over the file. It calls `StreamReader.ReadLine` underneath but it might be more efficient than handling `BufferedStream` over and over for 32MB chunks. So it would be as simple as:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    //process line 
}
```

Moreover, you have problem with your code because you can split line between 32MB chunks, which will not happen with the above code.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure the internal buffer being used will not exceed 32MB? (Even though it's safe to assume a single line won't be that large but stil...)

Comment: @YonatanNir, going through code of `File.ReadLines` we can see that `public StreamReader(string path, Encoding encoding) : this(path, encoding, true, StreamReader.DefaultBufferSize)` constructor is used, while `DefaultBufferSize` is simply 1024.

Comment: What if I also got a restriction that I can't read the file one line at a time?

Comment: @YonatanNir Are you trying to make this as difficult as possible for yourself? Please list all the other restrictions in your question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton This is a restriction I got. The title of my questions is about reading chunks but everyone were more comfortable with the simple line by line solution.

The restriction itself is:
"You cannot read the entire file, one line at a time. Maximum size of data read, except for the actual records that need to be returned for the query, cannot exceed 32MB."

Comment: SOOOOO SLOOOOW no way i would be able to use this