# How to select a specific line from a text file that starts with a certain word/string?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to not hardcode my tokens into my program but I can't figure out how to look for a specific line with a certain word from a text file.

My current code is:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\INPUTFILE.txt")
```

How can I modify this to find the line that starts with "CERTAINWORD", or give me a null if it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

```
var line = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\INPUTFILE.txt")
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("CERTAINWORD"));
if(line == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Not found");
```

You use the [ReadLines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines) method instead of ReadAllLines. This allows you to enumerate each line while you read them. Each line then is passed to the [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if it starts with the requested value. If a line matches the request then the enumaration is stopped and the line is returned, if no line matches the result is null.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\INPUTFILE.txt"))
{
    if (line.Contains("CERTAINWORD"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```