# Read CSV file from and to specific line numbers (e.g. 2 to 50)

Tags: c#, csv, readfile

I have a .csv file that currently is read all the lines:

```
 string csv = File.ReadAllText(@inputfile);
```

suppose there are 100 lines inside that file. I want to read it only from the second line until the 50th lines. how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ReadLines` method with LINQ:

```
File.ReadLines(inputFile).Skip(2).Take(48);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("inputfile.csv").Skip(1).Take(49);
```

modified answer based on all comments

Comment: @John before edit his answer was: `string line = File.ReadLines(@inputfile).Skip(2).Take(50);` which is totally valid. Why do you think that C# didn't works like that?

Comment: @vasily.sib Because `IEnumerable<string>` isn't assignable to `string` last time I checked. `File.ReadLines(filename)` returns `IEnumerable<string>`, and by association, so does the `.Skip(2)` and the `.Take(50)`. Also, in case anyone is wondering, I'm not the person who downvoted saravanakumar's answer.

Comment: Besides, it is wrong also because it takes 50 lines after the first two not till the 50th line

Comment: sorry for the edits and the logical mistake on 50 :|

Comment: @saravanakumarv after all these changes you ended up with an answer that is equal to the first correct one provided. At this point I would consider to delete this one

Comment: no, as you can see from timestamps, he was the first

Comment: the first one is logically wrong on skipping 2, taking 48 :P

Comment: the question is about reading from second line to 50 .. so skip 1 and take next 49.

Comment: @John, saravanakumar v answer is @ 2018-08-13 08:57:5**4**Z, Selman Genç answer @ 2018-08-13 08:57:5**6**Z and Milney answer @ 2018-08-13 08:58:30

Comment: @saravanakumar depends how you define 'from' and 'until' as inclusive or exclusive really...

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines, skip the first one and take the remaining 49

```
List<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(@inputFile).Skip(1).Take(49).ToList()
```

Comment: `ReadLines` in Selman's answer is better since it doesn't have to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: @John: well explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines