# Illegal Character in Path when creating folders

Tags: c#, directory, character

I have a program that mass creates directories based on a CSV file.  It runs through the loop but then it hits an "invalid characters in path" I need a validation (or if statement) to validate the folderName first and if it's invalid -reports it in a log file, then just proceed with the next folder creation.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(targetdir + "log.txt");

try
{
    string[] items = File.ReadAllLines(csv);

    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetdir + item);
        sw.WriteLine(item + " OK!");                    
    }                

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

sw.Close();
```

I'm not sure where to start. I feel like i have to add an "if else" but i'm not sure what to put. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` might be a good starting point :)

Comment: Your friend is the Path class

Comment: Use the debugger to see if `targetdir + item` is a valid path - especially since it is coming from somewhere else!  Also instead of string concatenation, use `Path.Combine` to create a file path name

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `targetdir + item`? Of `(targetdir + item).Length`?

Comment: `and if it's invalid -reports it in a log file` It isn't a _great_ solution, but a simple solution based on your current structure would be to add that logging inside of your `catch`. Also, read up on `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Where is this CSV coming from? Is it internal, or uploaded by users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main change you need to do in your code is stopping concatenating together the variables that creates the destination folder and start using the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) method.
In your specific case you could use [GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars) to have a list of characters not allowed to be part of a path or file name and then check if the current item contains any of those characters.

But there are other important changes to do.
First a StreamWriter is a disposable object and thus you should always create it inside a [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to have a correct cleaup of its internal resources when you have done with it or even if an abnormal exception occurs.
Second, it is better to use [File.ReadLines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines) instead of loading all the lines in memory with ReadAllLines

```
char[] invalidChars = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
string logFile = Path.Combine(targetdir, "log.txt");
try
{
   using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logFile))
   {
       foreach (string item in File.ReadLines(csv))
       {
           if(item.Any(x => invalidChars.Contains(x)))
                sw.WriteLine(item + " BAD");
           else
           {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(targetdir,item));
                sw.WriteLine(item + " OK!");                    
           }
       }
    }                
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Finally, I want to underline that in this context it is important to use **GetInvalidFileNameChars** and not **GetInvalidPathChars** because here we are checking the name of a folder. This name has the same rules used for files.
GetInvalidPathChars omits some characters that are valid in a *path* string like the *\* or the *?* and *. So for example GetInvalidPathChars doesn't have any issues with something like `C:\Windows\System32\*.dll` while this string contains characters not usable for a filename or for a single folder's name.

Comment: glad to see i m not the only one using try catch like this

Comment: i tried this but it's still not catching filenames with invalid characters

Comment: Can you give some example of these filenames? Consider that this checks for PATH invalid characters not files

Comment: Sorry.  When i said filenames i meant folderNames.  These are examples of the names contained in CSV:  ?1? , A--* , B< , BC> , D*a
I need my loop to ignore it.

Comment: I see, should change to GetInvalidFilenameChars

Comment: @Steve - Thanks! That did it.