# Removing text from a file

Tags: c#, io, text-files

Good morning! I have a **text file** that looks like this:

[image]

I want to make the **text file** look like this from my script:

[image]

My idea was to delete every "sign" from the right to the " | " so that only the username remains. Or removing everything from the left, from the first " | ". I only don't know how to code that. **Im thankful for any help!** If something's unclear, feel free to ask! :)

**File text:**

Jeff|14|0||4/7/2020 9:22:15 AM|0

Tom123|8|0||4/7/2020 10:47:36 AM|1

Comment: Don't you have any example code about what have you tried before? Just to give you a more acqurate answer.

Comment: open old file, create new file , read line, split by pipe, write first element(of split result) to new file, repeat(reading) until end of old file ... where is the problem?

Comment: @Selvin , i don't know the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) to gather the lines from the file into a `string[]`, then [`File.WriteAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) to write the lines back to the file. We can split each line on `'|'` using [`string.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8), then get the first item using [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) from LINQ. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file) has some good documentation on how to read text files.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

// other code

var path = "C:\\file.txt";

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(line => line.Split('|')[0]);

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

If you dealing with big files, it might be better to use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8), which reads one line at a time. This is different to `File.ReadAllLines()`, which reads the whole file into memory at once. You can have a look at [What is the difference between File.ReadLines() and File.ReadAllLines()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var someString = "Jeff|blah|foo|bar";
 var justJeff = someString.Substring(0, someString.IndexOf('|'));
```