# Is there any better/faster way to identify the length of line inside file in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any better/faster way to identify the length of line inside file in C#, by giving its line number
I have a console application where I need to find length of each line present in the file where I will be giving the line number in the file

```
int lineno = 5
int linelen = File.ReadLines(@"C\Document\myfile.txt").skip(lineno).Take(1).First().Length
```

Comment: Is this process slow currently? How slow is it? What speed would be acceptable? It's hard to do anything about performance without some benchmarks.

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a "line" in a file is. All files are a single stream of characters which can contain `\n` and/or `\r` characters. A "line" is just a human convenience.

Comment: Not sure why you have so much LINQ in there, `File.ReadLines(@"C\Document\myfile.txt")[lineno].Length` is so much shorter (and requires way fewer allocations)

Comment: @UnholySheep Need to use `.ElementAt(lineno)`, ReadLines gives an IEnumerable

Comment: @gunr2171 Ah, right - I had it mixed up with `ReadAllLines`...

Comment: I have 200 mb file where I have around 968355 lines. I have a function process on each of line in the file , this function will needs the length of each of line in the file and function passes line number to get length of the lines

Comment: `.Take(1)` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example, since its not clear what you need ar result:
code can be simplified base on what exectly you need in output. also, can add a where condition and take, skip, etc

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\1\\test\\mishka.txt")
    .Select((str, index) => new {index = index, line = str, length = str.Length});
    Console.Write(result);
```

[image]

Comment: Using `File.ReadAllLines` is potentially going to lead to terrible performance, especially with large files. Use `File.ReadLines` instead. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines

Comment: @DavidG, i agreed. it was an example to show how to appy linq
 ReadLines() is an iterator, it helps you to avoid calling ToArray() you need array to apply Select(). again this is an example