# File.ReadAllLines or Stream Reader

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, .net

We can read file either by using [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) or by using [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

For example I want to load each line into a `List` or `string[]` for further manipulation on each line.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\file.txt");

foreach(string line in lines)
{
     //DoSomething(line);
}
```

or

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       //DoSomething(line); or //save line into List<string>
    }
}

//if list is created loop through list here
```

Application come across different size of text file. Which could grow from few `KBs` to `MBs` occasionally.

My question is that which one is preferred way and why one should be preferred over other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line

Comment: Preferred for what purpose? Speed, memory or?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov thanks I am looking at the link.

Comment: @Steve, speed and memory both. If larger size text file comes then application should efficiently read all lines.

Comment: Then the link above should give you a full answer

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want to process each line of a text file without loading the entire file into memory, the best approach is like this:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("Filename"))
{
    // ...process line.
}
```

This avoids loading the entire file, and uses an existing .Net function to do so.

However, if for some reason you need to store all the strings in an array, you're best off just using `File.ReadAllLines()` - but if you are only using `foreach` to access the data in the array, then use `File.ReadLines()`.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain? Seems odd to downvote the correct answer... ;)

Comment: Probably downvoted because `File.ReadLines()` slurp the entire file into memory (a `string[]`).

Comment: @NicholasCarey No, it's the version that DOESN'T do that: `public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines()`... hence my comment "without loading the entire file into memory"

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree with you, though it's an old topic - upvoted for anybody going to read this and is beeing confused.

Answer (score 25):

[Microsoft](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs#8d10107b7a92c5c2) uses a StreamReader in File.ReadAllLines:

```
    private static String[] InternalReadAllLines(String path, Encoding encoding)
    {
        Contract.Requires(path != null);
        Contract.Requires(encoding != null);
        Contract.Requires(path.Length != 0);

        String line;
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                lines.Add(line);

        return lines.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `StreamReader` read the file line by line, it will consume less memory.
Whereas, `File.ReadAllLines` read all lines **at once** and store it into `string[]`, it will consume more memory. And if that `string[]` is larger than `int.maxvalue` then that will produce memory **overflow**(limit of 32bit OS).

So, for bigger files `StreamReader` will be more efficient.

Comment: Given Sam's answer about ReadAllLines using StreamReader internally, is this answer invalid?