# Use everything before a specific character

Tags: c#, text, split, streamreader

So, I've been learning C# and I need to remove everything after the
":" character.

I've used a StreamReader to read the text file, but then I can't use the Split function, then I tried it by using an int function to import it, but then again I can't use the Split function?

What I want this to do is import a text file that's written like;

name:lastname

name2:lastname2

And so that it only shows name and name2.
I've been searching this for a couple of days but I can't seem to figure it out!
I don't know what I'm doing wrong and how to import the text file without using StreamReader or anything else.

Edit:

I'm trying to post something to a website that goes like;

example.com/q=(name without ":")

Edit 2:

```
StreamReader list = new StreamReader(@"list.txt");
string reader = list.ReadToEnd();
string[] split = reader.Split(":".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(split);
```

gives output as;

```
System.String[]
```

Comment: I don't really have an example, I removed all the code that I used.

Comment: Have you looked at [StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend(v=vs.110).aspx)?   That returns a string, which you could then use `Split` on.

Comment: Use String.indexOf and String.substring

Comment: I edited it, thanks for the help. It itsn't solved yet.

Comment: @JeroenVelde if you have 1 entry per line you can just read the line as string and use `.Replace(":", " ");` instead of split https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989887/342740

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few issues here.  First, use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `StreamReader`, its much simpler and easier:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines("path/to/file");
```

Next, your lines variable needs to be iterated so you can get to each line of the collection:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //TODO: write split logic here
}
```

Then you have to split each line on the `':'` character:

```
string[] split = line.Split(":");
```

Your `split` variable is an array of string (i.e `string[]`) which means you have to access a specific *index* of the array if you want to see its value. This is your second issue, if you pass `split` to `Console.WriteLine()` under the hood it just calls `.ToString()` on the object you have passed it, and with a `string[]` it won't automatically give you all the values, you have to write that yourself.

So if your `line` variable was: `"name:Steve"`, the split variable would have two indexes and look like this:

```
//split[0] = "name"
//split[1] = "Steve"
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Wa5aR) that demonstrates.

Comment: Nice job explaining every bit of it!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me fix it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I your file size small and your name:lastname in one line use:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("filaPath");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     var array = line.Split(':');
     if (array.Length > 0)
     {
         var name = array[0];
      }
}
```

if name:lastname isn't in new line tell me how it's seprated