# Listview filled with files from folders filter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem and i dont know how to handle it, tips would be much appriciated.

I have a listview filled up with TXT files from a folder on my desktop
i need it to filter trough a datepicker

The files in the folders are for example called `10-10-2018.TXT, 11-10-2018.TXT`.

After I picked my date through datepicker I want only that file to show up.

This is what I have.

```
Public partial class StartAnalyse : Window
{
    string currentitem = string.Empty;
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\folder1");

    private void LV1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataFromFolders1();
    }


    public void DataFromFolders1()
    {

        LV1.Items.Clear();

        if (dinfo.Exists)
        {
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)

            {
                LV1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }

private void DatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //here i convert the selected date to string

    String date = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).ToString("d/MM/yyyy");

    // here i need help
}
```

Comment: Do you need the contents of the file to be displayed somewhere. I presume yes. Refer https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989677/file-readalllines-or-stream-reader to load the content into memory and then set it to control's text property (e.g. richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllLines(%filenameWithPath%)

Comment: Not the content just the file name my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an optional parameter to your DataFromFolders1 method and use it when filtering the files with `GetFiles()`:

```
 public void DataFromFolders1(string fileName = "*")
{
    LV1.Items.Clear();
    if (dinfo.Exists)
    {
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles($"{fileName}.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)

        {
            LV1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

In your `DatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged` method, you can call it with the string as parameter.

```
private void DatePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string date = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // Note the format change to fit your file names
    DataFromFolders1(date);
}
```

Comment: Hmm my listview is loaded with the files but its invisible.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l4expk.

you can see under the listview 6 files are loaded but not shown

Comment: So, what is the value of the string parameter fileName? Is it the name of a existing file?

Comment: if i hover over File Name it says File name = "* "

Comment: Why so, if you used my code. The formatted date string is sent as parameter to DataFromFolders1(string)?

Comment: Also, it works after i pick a date only 1 file is loaded.
but now its invisble