# Why File.ReadLines() in C# allocates too much memory?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have twenty 10MB txt files and would like to read these files.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989677), which says `File.ReadLines()` doesn't load entire lines so it doesn't spend much memory.

```
var directory = "path/to/files";

foreach (var filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.txt"))
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
    {
        // I will do something here, but not yet.
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, Jetbrains Rider DPA says like below image.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

**Environment**: .NET Core Console Application (6.0)

**Edit**

Same problem with `StreamReader`.

[image]

Comment: How much RAM does your machine have? .NET will gladly consume gigabytes of RAM and never release it back to the OS unless the OS asks it nicely via a memory-pressure signal. Also, you're running a `DEBUG` build, right? So what happens if you profile a Release build?

Comment: Do you get the same allocation if you use a StreamReader?

Comment: What encoding are those 10MB `.txt` files using? If it's ASCII or UTF-8, then be aware that (absent any memory-pressure or GC events) your program may consume up to `10 * 20 * 2 == 400 MiB` of memory for all of the enumerated `string` values because internally .NET uses UTF-16, so (for example) loading a 128KB UTF-8 file into memory will use 256KB of actual memory.

Comment: @Dai I ran my code with Debug build. But Rider didn't notice me when using Release build. Is there any difference between Debug and Release when `File.ReadLines()` is executed?

Comment: @Ellisein "Is there any difference between Debug and Release when File.ReadLines() is executed?" - **yes** (well, not `ReadLines` specifically, but the GC itself behaves differently): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165353/does-garbage-collection-run-during-debug and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462378/why-c-sharp-garbage-collection-behavior-differs-for-release-and-debug-executable

Comment: @gunr2171 It seems that there is no same problem with `StreamReader`, But I wonder why `File.ReadLines()` differs.

Comment: Because `ReadLines` doesn't Buffer like a Stream can. Think about it, its loading strings into the Managed Heap and they are still kept in memory (for debugging especially).

Comment: It's interesting, since `ReadLines` essentially uses `StreamReader` (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/io/ReadLinesIterator.cs)). Is it possible that in your test of `StreamReader`, you're not running it in a way that Rider understands it to be the memory usage of one method?

Comment: OMG, that was my mistake. Same problem occured with `StreamReader`.

Comment: In my tests with .NET 6, and BenchmarkDotNet with a MemoryDiagnoser, Running a 10MB file (each line is 500 characters) through both methods only allocated 34MB in both cases.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I used 20 files for test, can you please do same with more files?

Comment: I'm currently running code to generate a load of files with unique strings. I'll get back to you with the benchmark result :)

Comment: Current result for 20 10MB files is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xw4m.png), based on [these tests](https://pastebin.com/cSuzEG4i). I'm currently running a bigger set of 10 GB's worth of data.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar It seems that allocated memory increased by the number of files. Thanks for the test :)

Comment: Testing with 10 GB worth of files, it seems that the total allocation hit 33 GB, but in the 3 GC generations, we only had about  2.8 GB, so stuff is getting garbage collected correctly. [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T42ms.png)