# Reading line by line from textfile

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a function in c# class which is reading a textfile into streamreader.Here is the c# function.

```
public readFile(string fileName, long startPosition = 0)
    {
        //Open the file as FileStream
        _fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        _reader = new StreamReader(_fileStream);
        //Set the starting position
        _fileStream.Position = startPosition;

    }
```

and i am trying to call this function into another class and read the file line by line.

```
 private AddedContentReader _freader;
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            _freader = new AddedContentReader(file);    

    }
```

So my question is how to read the textfile line by line in the calling function

Please help me..

Comment: have you checked [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StreamReader` class has a method called `ReadLine`.

#### Sample

```
string line;
while((line = _reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - StreamReader.ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: One small query `protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            _freader = new AddedContentReader(file);    

    }` inside this method because i am keeping my logic here..

Comment: If you want to use it in you OnStart method, why not return it from the readfile method.

Comment: Iam not sure what you want to do exactly. Do you want to use your StreamReader in your OnStart Method? What is you AddedContentReader doing?

Answer (score 0):

Use while loop to read till the line is empty or nil. I hope below code will help you.

```
TextReader yourfile;
yourfile = File.OpenText("Your File Path");

while ((str = yourfile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

//write your code here
}

yourfile.Close();
```

Comment: Sir, what is the data type of yourFile? A foo or a bar?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get all the lines first and then loop through them using the readlines method of system.IO in code such as the following:

```
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
            int count = 0;                

            while(lines.Length > count)
            {
                function1(lines[count]]);
                count++;        
            }
```

Comment: I think the loop is infinite and it will get out of it. I think you should use count instead of 0 in while loop