# Get value from txt file c#

Tags: c#

I am currently developing an application in C #, I need to recover the values of socks from a txt file here are the information in the txt file

> 104.131.163.123:2541
>   104.131.178.167:2541

I need to read the file line by line for each row and retrieve the value of the IP and the port value and put them in a list

this my code :

I need to read the file line by line for each row and retrieve the value of the IP and the port value and put them in a list
this is my code

```
List<string[]> list  = new List<string[]>();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (@"C:\");
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`enter code here`
            {
                string[] array = line.Spit(":");
                list.Add(array);
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Hwat have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?  There are plenty of tutorials on reading text files (including the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx))

Comment: i have search in msdn in multiple book but no result

Comment: did you first search [how to read from txt file](https://www.google.com/search?q=+how+to+read+from+txt+file+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Comment: I think you're confusing Stack Overflow with a write-my-code-for-me site. We're here to assis when you have a problem, not write code based on a spec you provide.

Comment: [I think this is what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Comment: i have modified , i not want to write code for me , i need a help  Craig W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code reads all lines of a file and add each ip address into a list

```
private List<string> GetIPAddress()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    var input = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
         string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
         string port = match.Groups[2].Value;
         list.Add(ip);
         // you can also add port in the list
     }
     return list;
}
```

Comment: @user3537566 your welcome :)

Comment: i want to change all this in function to return for me list of ip and port what i should do ??