# Text file to 1D Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text-files

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.  My question is about VB.NET and converting a text file to a 1D array.

My text file will contain 30 names of technology companies.  I want the data values read from TECHNOLOGY into a 1D array called 'companies'.  I then want all the companies output with each on a new line.

Please let me know how I can improve my code / correct it fully.  Thanks!

```
Dim sr As New Streamreader("Companies")
Dim words as string=""
Dim company(30) as string
Dim I as Integer=0

Do Until sr.Peek=1
Word=sr.Readline()
company(i)=word

Lstwords.Items.Add(words(i))

i=i+1
```

[link to code as an Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loEsS.png)

Comment: Please put the code right into the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line

Read this for more ideas. Although, I don't think you will see much difference in a file this small.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using File.ReadAllLines

```
'Load each line of the file into an element of a string array
Dim companies() as string = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Companies")

For each company as string in companies
   Console.WriteLine(company)
next
```

Comment: That's all he really needs:         `For Each company As String In` `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Companies")`
            `Console.WriteLine(company)`
        `Next`

Comment: @Claudius That fails to put the data into an array named `companies`.

Comment: true but it looks like op wants it for that single reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean at the end by "output each on a new line", so I've just done it in the console.

```
    Dim companies(29) As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader
    Dim filename As String
    filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(
    My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "companies.txt")

    If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        sr = IO.File.OpenText(filename)
        Do While sr.Peek <> -1
            companies(i) = sr.ReadLine
            i += 1
        Loop
        sr.Close()
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("File not found")
    End If

    For Each company As String In companies
        Console.WriteLine(company)
    Next
```

Be aware that this code won't work if you don't have exactly 30 lines of companies in the text file. Modify the code above to deal with contingencies.

Comment: Thanks @p3tch however I'm a bit confused.  Why is it Dim companies(29) as string, not dim companies(30) as string?

Comment: Hi Alex, it's because arrays are zero-based. So `myArray(5)` would actually be the 6th item in the array. Similarly if you want to declare an array of 6 values, you would do so like `Dim values(5) As Integer`

Comment: Also, have you considered using a List instead of an Array? You don't need to specify the length when declaring a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve this code :

```
Dim sr As New Streamreader("Companies")
Dim word As String = "" 'To remember the current word
Dim company(30) as string 'The list of companies
Dim i as Integer = 0 'a counter

Word = sr.Readline() 'We read the first line

While Not IsNothing(Word) 'While we read a line (See EDIT for explanation)
    Company(i) = word 'We add the word
    Lstwords.Items.Add(word) 'I suppose this is a list that you want to display
    i += 1 'Increment the counter
    Word = sr.ReadLine() 'Read the next line
End While 'End of the loop
```

**EDIT : Why use Not IsNothing(Word)**

If you look at the [ReadLine() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you find out that when the end of file is reached, that function will return Nothing.

So this is a necessary and sufficient way to know we are not at the end of the file.

Comment: thanks!  could you please explain the line: Not IsNothing(Word)

i.e, why is that needed?  Can it function without?  Thanks!