# How to copy specific lines from one file to another?

Tags: c#, file, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a text file with about 3000 lines. Some lines start with numbers and some with text. For example:

Lines that start with numbers:

001 some text

0017 some text

8 some text...

Lines that start with text:

some text,

some text...

I want to copy lines that start with numbers to result.text.

Lines that start with text to log.txt.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is plain simple. Show us something you have tried and then we might help you out with your homework.

Comment: For this read and write in another file.

Comment: {string line;
        String Report = Char.IsDigit; //not working
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))          
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("newfile.txt"))


            while (reader.ReadLine() != null)                   
            {
                if (reader.ReadLine().StartsWith(Report))
                {
                    //writes/starts a new line beginning with ReportRequest
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }}

Comment: @LuisVito - please edit your question. Code doesn't go into comments

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line) out to learn how to read line by line. After that, just check the first character from each of those lines. If it's a digit (use Char.IsDigit Method), write it to a file, if it's not, write it to the other. You can do the research on how to write to files yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in one statement for one file

```
WriteAllLines("new file", 
    ReadLines("source file")
    .Where(line => line.Lenth > 0 && Char.IsDigit(line[0]))
);
```

Note that it works on a line-by-line basis internally, i.e. there will be only one line at a time in memory. One line will be read from input processed and written to the output, then the next line and so on. This is because these methods work with `IEnumerable<string>`. `IEnumerable` does not buffer the whole file as would be the case if you read the file into an array, for instance.

---

You would have to repeat this twice for the two output files. Therefore I suggest the following approach, which reads the input file only once:

```
using (var log = CreateText("log.txt"))
using (var result = CreateText("result.txt")) {
    foreach (string line in ReadLines("source file")) {
        if (line.Length > 0) {
            if (Char.IsDigit(line[0])) {
                result.WriteLine(line);
            } else {
                log.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This second approach does not buffer the file either.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

### Okay here is how i would do it

- use [File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) to read your text file into a string[]
- create 2 string [Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) to save "results" and "logs"
- for each string in the string array get the first character with [charAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k1twzbb(v=vs.100).aspx)
- use [Char.IsNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y(v=vs.110).aspx) to know to what List you should Add() the line you are working on
- use File again to write the Lists to different files

this is enough of a hint incase this is your homework. do your research!