# what will be the c# code to copy only certain lines from the text file containing the lines to another file at particular place?

Tags: c#, file-io

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

from the above code , which was placed in some text file , i need to convert it to angular 2 code by using file handling methods in c#.
so i need to replace

ng-model to [(ngModel)]

and i need to copy from 7th line i.e .,

... to

to some text  file...it acts as `component.html` and i need to copy

```
$scope.first Name = "John";
$scope.last Name = "Doe";
```

and removing $scope we get,

```
first Name = "John";
last Name = "Doe";
```

This need to b copied and place in one text file file which already contains the basic code( like import...) to represent the component.ts file..

Comment: AngularJS and Angular2 aren't the same concept at all. You can't simply parse a file to another and expect it to work.

Comment: i just need to convert basic codes like this to angular 2 thats it

Comment: If that's just it, then do it by hand.

Comment: this is my project... i need to make a c# code to do this..

Comment: So you don't even try and ask on SOF ? We're not code monkeys.

Comment: by using  c#files.. iam not aware of files concepts

Comment: Then read the documentation and make you own work.

Comment: i just want to know how to copy certain lines from a particular text file

Comment: Literally 5 seconds on Google : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37377576/how-to-copy-specific-lines-from-one-file-to-another