# How to extract line between 2 lines in c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with content as:

```
**************

Some text

**************
```

I want to read the text between **** in c#.
How can I achieve the same in c sharp

Comment: read each line, look for line =*****", process next lines, looking at each till you see "****" again

Comment: i mean, rly, write some code

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the contents of the file, then [`Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove the unwanted contents of the file:

```
var result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\path\to\file.txt")
    .Replace("*", string.Empty) // remove the asterisks
    .Trim(); // trim whitespace and newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to read lines from a text file in general : [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

You can do this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
int numLines = lines.Length;
for (int lineCounter = 1 /*discard the first*/;lineCounter<Length-1 /*discard the last*/;lineCounter++)

{
     Do whatever you want with lines[lineCounter]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the **** count then this might help.

```
 string readContents; 
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
{ 
    readContents = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    int start = readContents.IndexOf("*****") + 1; 
    int end = readContents.LastIndexOf("*****", start); 
    string result = readContents.Substring(start, end - start);

}
```

Comment: That will also read the ******* lines

Comment: @MartinBrown Code updated. Please check

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Suppose the file contains "*****\r\nSome Text\r\n*****". Variable `start` would end up being 1. LastIndex of then looks for "*****" in the string ending at 1. ie it looks for "*****" in "*". `end` then becomes -1 making substring fail.