# how to download large file in mvc without loading it in memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Code:

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName) {
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), fileName);
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    return File(fileBytes,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, can you please ask a question and provide any context to assist in answering? Thanks!

Comment: Hi I am trying to download a large file from server and it is loading in memory first.How can i prevent the whole process from loading in memory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)