# How do I insert lines of a external txt file into the domainupdown items in visual c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, line

How do I insert lines of a external text file into the domainupdown items in visual c#?
each line of text must correspond to a single items.

```
domainUpDown.Items.Add(line1);
domainUpDown.Items.Add(line2);
domainUpDown.Items.Add(lines n);
```

ecc

Comment: What doesn't work with your code? Are you really asking how to retrieve all lines of a text file?

Comment: yes i'm a newbie!

Comment: No problem. But you could have searched this. There are plenty of [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line) and [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time) also helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from: https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-readalllines

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\rearrange.txt");
foreach(var line in lines)
{
   domainUpDown.Items.Add(line);
}
```