# Access to path is denied when string is defined and not when using quotes

Tags: c#

I am having a very strange issue right now.
I am attempting to get the files of a directory by using this code:

```
public static string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@File.ReadAllText(Settings.localdir.Trim()));
```

However, when I do this, I get this error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\lazho\Desktop' is denied.
```

But when I do this code:

```
public static string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\lazho\Desktop");
```

It works without any errors. I have no idea why one would throw an error when they both equal the same value. Any Ideas?

P.S. I have already tried this:

```
public static string dir = @File.ReadAllText(Settings.localdir.Trim());
    public static string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
```

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles(@File.ReadAllText(Settings.localdir.Trim()));` - to check we're on the same page, this will read the directory from a text file (whose location is defined by `Settings.localdir.Trim()` and then get the list of files within that directory? Does the error path represent the value provided by `Settings.localdir.Trim()` or the directory in the text file?

Comment: @John Yes, it reads the directory from a text file. The error path represents exactly what it should,.

Comment: "The error path represents exactly what it should." - Let me rephrase, is the `ReadAllText` part throwing the exception, or the `GetFiles` part?

Comment: @John Ah, the GetFiles. It is reading the text fine and it equals exactly what it should, but when it attempts to get the files it throws the Access denied error.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're getting such an error. I've tried the same on my machine (text file points to `c:\users\john\desktop`) and your first line works for me.

Comment: @John Exactly, this is strange. I have tried running it as an admin as well and it still doesn't read it. This is odd because it was working before as well, and I didn't change anything about the code or the text file and it suddenly became unable to get the files.

Comment: Does the file have newline in the end or something? Is it *really* character by character correct, so it doesn’t have a newline in the end?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yep, it's completely correct. I am even trimming the file. It is only a single line, and when I print it to the console and print the quoted text they are identical.

Comment: You’re not trimming it in this code example at least

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Settings.localdir.Trim() is the code im using. Either way, it shouldn't matter. Here is what the file looks like: https://i.imgur.com/ulZTPYd.png

Comment: That trims the file path, not the contents of the file. But if a debugger says it’s exactly the same (not printing it out, checking it in a debugger for exact match) then it’s not that

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, they are an exact match.

Comment: @LazHoll You can try simple test to check if it's really the same string `@File.ReadAllText(Settings.localdir.Trim()).equals(@"C:\Users\lazho\Desktop")`

Comment: @Guy I have tried that. They are the same.

Comment: You are doing two different things `ReadAllText` and `GetFiles` is not the same. opening a file seem to throw an exception but listing the files does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SecurityException` is from `File.ReadAllText` method. you can not read drive `C` without permission.

[ReadAllTextDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: When running it as an administrator I still get this issue.

Comment: @Guy  Directory.GetFiles only get filenames.

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour I am aware of that, I am trying to know what the names of all the files are on the directory specified in the text file.

Comment: @Guy Yes, when using `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\lazho\Desktop")` I dont get this issue, but when reading from the text file with an identical string it does not work.

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour The OP uses `Directory.GetFiles` in both cases. The only difference is where the path is coming from. And in both cases the path leads to `C`.

Comment: @LazHoll if you need read from Desktop use Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour I will need to read from any folder written on the text file. I'm just using the desktop as an example.

Comment: @LazHoll use this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)