# Getting count of first character in a text file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a large text file that looks like this where there is one row with an A at the beginning and one C at the end and an x number of B's in between:

A

B

B

B

C

What's the best way to get a number count for the number of times A, B, or C appear? All of these rows have more data but this is what I'm trying to achieve.

Do I have to read in the whole file or is reading it one line at a time the best?

Comment: Either will work, it depends on the file size, and how you want to accomplish the task. Reading by lines is easiest in either case. I would suggest considering LINQ and `File.ReadAllLines()`.

Comment: If you always have 1 A, 1 C, and the rest B, you already know how many A's and C's there are, to count number of B's, do `File.ReadLines(...).Count() - 2`.

Comment: How big is the file? The suggestions so far assume you can read the entire file into memory. Another way is to iterate over each line in the file. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line

Comment: @RalphWillgoss Actually, the comment to use `File.ReadLines` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like that would work

```
foreach (var grouping in File.ReadAllLines("<file-path-here>").GroupBy(x => x[0]))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"char: {grouping.Key}, count: {grouping.Count()}");
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the file contained an empty line. I suggest doing `GroupBy(x => x)`, and then inside the `foreach` check if `grouping.Key` is an empty line (you could use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`), and print the result, or use it, only if not.

Comment: Or just add a `.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` before the .GroupBy

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet of code is a easy implementation:

```
 int iBCount = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Count -2;
 int iACount = 1; // We already knew this
 int iCCount = 1; // We already knew this
```

Also, if you know size in bytes of each line (they must be the same for each line) and you are concerned with the performance then you can simply calculate the number of "B" lines as follows

```
 // There will be no problem with typecast if each lines is the same length in bytes
 int iBLines = (int)(new System.IO.FileInfo(pathToFile).Length / FIXED_LINE_SIZE_IN_BYTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)

int A_count = 0, B_count = 0, C_count = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    switch(line[0])
    {
        case 'A':
            A_count++;
            break;
        case 'B':
            B_count++;
            break;
        case 'C':
            C_count++;
    }
}
```