# Convert OpenImage Coordinates to DarkNet format

Tags: c#, .net, yolo

How can i Converting Screen space Coordinates to **DarkNet Yolo** format?

Image Dimensions:

```
width: 1024
height: 768
```

Box Dimensions:

```
x: 51.84
y: 175.359741
width: 988.16
height: 639.999756
```

Normalization i understand with the division of point to image, as x = x/width
but to convert the x,y,width,height coordination to darknet format.

if anyone can point me in a c# direction

btw *what is the darknet format called?*, since the original is screen-space.
that would make googling a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) might be helpful. The YOLO format is:

`<object-class> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height>`

where all the `<x_center> , <y_center> , <width> , <height>` are float values relative to width and height of image, it can be equal from 0.0 to 1.0.

- width = width of object / width of image
- height = height of object / height of image
- x_center and y_center are the center coordinates of each object

For example, to calculate the center:

- x_center = (x_min + (x_max - x_min)/2) / image_width
- y_center = (y_min + (y_max - y_min)/2) / image_width

---

In your example:

```
width = 988.16 / 1024
height = 639.999756 / 768
x_center = (51.84 + 988.16) / (2 * 1024)
y_center = (175.359741 + 639.999756) / (2 * 768)
```

I am not sure how your text files look like. It would help if you could post a sample of your text files to [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038746/6129428) and convert.
I also don't know what the Darknet format is called.