# How can I only extract numbers from a textfile in win forms?

Tags: c#

This is what my text file looks like (example)

```
28:Toy
1:Chocolate bar
10:Water bottle
```

I want it to only extract the numbers, then add the numbers together and put it into a label or something
I've tried

```
foreach(int number in "money.txt"){
    int sum = number + number;
    label5.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the fastest way to read a text file line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VERY IMPORTANT !**

Your code:

```
foreach(int number in "money.txt"){
    int sum = number + number; // BIG ERROR
    label5.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

You have make a big mistake with `int sum = number + number;`.

Take `sum` to out of your scope (maybe `global`) first.

You have to do 2 steps:

Try this online [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C4sYU7)

Step 1: Read content of your file:

```
using System.IO;

// Your code
static string yourTextFileContent = File.ReadAllText("money.txt");
```

Step 2: I wrote a method to do your work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    // Demo string
    static string yourMoney = @"28:Toy
1:Chocolate bar
10:Water bottle";
    // Your real string
    //static string yourTextFileContent = File.ReadAllText("money.txt");
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using IEnumerable");
        // int sum = 0;
        foreach (int item in GetEnumerableIntFromString(yourMoney))
        {
            sum += item;
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
        //label5.Text = sum.ToString();
    }

    // Using IEnumerable
    private static IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerableIntFromString(string str)
    {
        string[] splitLine = str.Split(new[]{'\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(string item in splitLine)
        {
            string[] splitToGetNumber = item.Split(new[]{':'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            yield return Convert.ToInt32(splitToGetNumber[0].Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

If you have an `Enumerable`, you want to Convert to `List`:

```
Enumerable<int> enumerable = yourEnumerable;
List<int> asList = enumerable.ToList();
```

Comment: Over complicating a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

```
var summ = 0;
var file = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
foreach (var line in file)
    {
        var number = int.Parse(line.Split(":")[0]);
        summ += number;
    }
    label5.Text = summ.ToString();
```

Something like this can be base, which you can use for your needs.

Comment: Getting error "Cannot convert char to string" When I click on it, it brings me to the foreach keyword.

Comment: I created a simple app to try it. This code worked for me. Variable summ was the same, as the summ of numbers in file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution.

1. Read in the file
2. Parse the first element of the string (split with :)
3. Sum it up.

```
    var sumOfAllInts = File.ReadAllLines(textFile).ToList().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Split(':').First())).Sum();
```

Comment: What would be the variable in this situation? - since I want to put it in a label.

Comment: @leonlejunchen Does this answer your question? please mark it answered if so.