# Read line for line and write line for line

Tags: c#

How do I read from a file which has many lines with each one word and then write a file which just extends the words with something?

For example my imports.txt has these lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

now I want to get this app to write a new file (exported.txt) which exports something like this

```
line1, price1
line2, price1
line3, price1
```

all of the text which gets attached to the string is always the same.

```cs
const Int32 BufferSize = 128;

using (var FileStream = File.OpenRead("import.txt"))
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(FileStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
                {
                    string line;
                    while((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

is this the right approach?

Comment: You can iterate [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines), build a `List<string>` that contains the rebuilt output strings, then [File.WriteAllLines(Your List)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines). If the input file is very large, then use two streams: one reads a line, the other writes a line with the modified string.

Comment: Is it possible to read the whole file at once with `FileReadAllLines()`, then the "import.txt" would be locked for less time. You can then iterate through the `string[]` which is returned.

Comment: Yes, what issue have you faced? Build you other export file and input and save

Comment: About the comments suggesting reading all the lines at once and then iterate: be careful that it might not be a good option for performance purposes, if the file is very big.

Comment: @Pac0 Is right, if performance is an issue you should `StreamReader` like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are just reading from a file.

The easiest approach would be to read all lines from your "import.txt" by using
[`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1)

And then iterate through the lines using `foreach/for` and manipulate the string.

After that you can use [`File.WriteAllLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netcore-3.1) to save your manipulated strings to the export file.

Like @Pac0 mentioned: Consider *not* using `File.ReadAllLines()` when performance is an issue see
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line).

Comment: In my while loop I did this: 

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("export.txt"))
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(line + ", test");
                            }

but its only reading the last line of import.txt and attaches ", test" to it.

Comment: This is the case because you instantiate a new `StreamWriter` for each line, when the `using` block in in the `while` loop.  You have to wrap the using of the `StreamWriter` around the `while loop` ```using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\git\export.txt", false))
                    {
                        string line;
                        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            streamWriter.WriteLine(line + ", test");
                        }
                    }```

Comment: Your current code creates a new `StreamWriter` for each line you write. The default setting for `append` is false, so your previous line get overwritten and only the last one survives.