# c# Disk I\O efficiency improvement read multiple lines at a time

Tags: c#, text-files, disk-io

It's common knowledge that disk I\O is expensive.
I typically read one line at a time using C# from a .txt file.
It just crossed my mind that if C# were to give you a way of reading 100 lines a time, it would require less round trips to the disk, and hence decrease time.
Is this possible?
Does anybody have any ideas on how to make this more efficient.
I am going through a file of 1 million rows in about an hour, reading and processing one line at a time.
I am wanting to see if I can significantly reduce this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8037070/495455

Answer (score 5):

A `FileStream` does this for you, It has an internal buffer and reads the file in chunks. It just so happens `File.ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` which is based on a `FileStream` and returns an `IEnumerable` based on lines.. It in essense does *everything* for you.

My suggestion would be to just use [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netcore-3.1)

If you need more fine-grained control over the internal buffer and chunk size, use `FileStream` with `StreamReader` which allows configuration of these concerns, among other things...

Comment: that is a very interesting idea.  i will try it out one of these days.  the drawback i see right now is that you will be reading one big long file in just one statement, and that might take time, and it might be hard to give a progress bar on that.  But maybe it won't take that long to read a million rows.  I don't know.  I have to try it out...

Comment: "*one big long file in just one statement*" no its actually not correct, you will be enumerating the file line by line, which will inturn be reading in chunks as you are enumerating it. The file does not get read in one big chunk unless its fits in the standard chunk size of 4k