# Removing numeration in .srt file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, srt

I am an amateur in coding and I'm struggling with a simple problem. I need to remove the numeration in the .srt file, but I couldn't find the correct regex, using regex might be a bad idea, because the subtitle itself can contain a number, I was thinking about matching "-->" and then removing the previous line, but I couldn't do it. Can someone help me?

I need to remove the following lines (numeration)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEDMS.png)

**UPDATE**

I came up with the following code, which replaces numbers with spaces, but it doesn't delete the line, as I want

```
var source = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\temp1\\Doctor.Strange.2016.720p.BluRay.x264.[YTS.MX]-English.srt");
var newFile = @"C:\Users\name\Desktop\temp1\new.srt";
for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
{
    if (source[i].Contains(matchSymbol))
    {
        source[i - 1] = "";
    }
}
File.WriteAllLines(newFile, source);
```

Comment: Please don't post the srt as an image. Post it as text so that we can use it to test our answers.

Comment: Does this work? `File.WriteAllLines(newFile, source.Where(x => !int.TryParse(x, out int _)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not super large, a better way would be to [read every line of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037070/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line) and check each line with [Int32.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__). If True is returned for that line, skip it, otherwise write the contents of the line to an output file.

Comment: what if i want to do it with ReadAllText and WriteAllText?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
void RemoveNumberLines()
{
    var source = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\temp1\\Doctor.Strange.2016.720p.BluRay.x264.[YTS.MX]-English.srt");
    var newFile = @"C:\Users\name\Desktop\temp1\new.srt";
    var matchSymbol = "-->";
    var myNewFile = new List<string>(); bool addPrevious = true; string previous = "";
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        addPrevious = !item.Contains(matchSymbol);
        if (addPrevious)
        {
            myNewFile.Add(previous);
        }
        previous = item;
    }
    if (addPrevious)
    {
        myNewFile.Add(previous);
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(newFile, myNewFile);
}
```

Adding the previous line, if the active line won't contain "-->".