Prevent loss of focus in a TextBox while text is edited via code, in C# WinForm
I am developing a desktop application that reads lines from a text file, processes them, and displays them sequentially in a multiline TextBox. The reading and processing process is very long and a new line appended to the TextBox every 2/3 seconds. Meanwhile, the user should be able to check the processed text in the TextBox and edit it, correcting some possible processing errors. At the end of the long process, by pressing a button the text present in the TextBox processed by code and corrected at the same time by the user will be saved to a file.
As you have probably guessed, the problem consists in the fact that every 2/3 seconds, that is when another processed line is added via code to the same TextBox, the TexBox which perhaps the user was editing loses focus.
I am using
TextBox.AppendText(text)
to add a new line to the TextBox (every 2/3 seconds) but this does not prevent the loss of focus.

I have a feeling that there are too many I/O operations going on in your program. I can't see the way you're reading from the file, but it seems like you're reading from the file line-by-line. This is quite a slow approach and might explain why adding a new line to the textbox takes long. There are many faster approaches that you can consider, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8038746/9972139

Thank you, but perhaps I was hasty in explaining how reading from file is done. I confirm that I use a StreamReader applied to the user's chosen filename via an OpenFileDialog. The “long” part of the process is not the reading from the file but the computation on the read line which is incompressible. Thank you.

You can try this wrapper for AppendText. It should help a bit but keep in mind it's more of a 80/20 solution.
If the user is editing very fast, also doing quick selections etc or the content added is way bigger than the textbox visible size, then you will inevitably see glitches and/or jumps in the content from time to time. Updating the control in parallel with user input and programmatic input is error prone and probably not a good idea from UX point of view
private void SafeAppendText(string line)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action<string>(SafeAppendText), line);
        return;
    }

    int selStart = textBox.SelectionStart;
    int selLength = textBox.SelectionLength;

    textBox.AppendText(line);

    textBox.SelectionStart = selStart ;
    textBox.SelectionLength = selLength ;
    textBox.ScrollToCaret();
}


You could try to remember the current text selection before adding text, then set the focus to the textbox again and restore the previous selection.
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save editing state
    int selStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
    int selLength = textBox1.SelectionLength;

    // Append line
    string line = GetNextLine();
    textBox1.Text += line + "\r\n";

    // Restore state
    // textBox1.Focus();   Focus gets not lost, so don't call this.
    textBox1.SelectionStart = selStart;
    textBox1.SelectionLength = selLength;

    // End condition I used in my test.
    // (In your case when the end of file is reached).
    lineCount++;
    if (lineCount > 50) {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
}

The tests I made indicate that the selection gets lost but not the focus (i.e., this TextBox is still the active control). The line textBox1.Focus(); is actually not necessary and it will only prevent the user from accessing another control.
Note that timer1_Tick is called in the UI-thread. So, no Invoke() required.

Btw., I simulated reading lines like this:
private string GetNextLine()
{
    int lineLength = Random.Shared.Next(80);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sb.Length < lineLength) {
        int wordLength = Random.Shared.Next(2, 12);
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            sb.Append((char)('a' + Random.Shared.Next(26)));
        }
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}


I thank you for the suggestions. Thanks to them I found a solution that solves the problem, even if the user types very fast.
private void ReadManageAndWriteLine()
{
    // open file with StreamReader
    // for every line in the file, read it and do what you need to do
    // then save the result in String outpuLine
    int cp = GetCaretPosition();
    txtBox.AppendText(outputLine + new string[] { Environment.NewLine });
    SetCaretPosition(cp);
    // go to the next line
}

private int GetCaretPosition()
{
    int s = txtBox.SelectionStart;
    return s;
}

private void SetCaretPosition(int cp)
{
    txtBox.Select(cp, 0);
    txtBox.Focus();
    txtBox.ScrollToCaret();
}

Again, thank you so much, problem solved.

This answer is redundant. You should accept and upvote the answer Instead of saying thank you

Wow there is no relaxation anywhere on the internet, huh? I simply wanted to thank those who had helped me by also reporting the exact implementation I had adopted using both suggestions, which were equally helpful. This is precisely why I took a moment to decide which of the two to vote for as the final solution. Then, with all due respect, you have not made a contribution in this thread, so your comment seems to me to be definitely out of place. Anyway, have a nice day and, really, relax a bit ;)
